# Shell script: command output becomes one line after saving it into a varible

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to process the output of a command multiple times(for different purposes).

However, after saving the output into a variable, the originally multi-line output is squeezed into one.

For example:

```
$ l=`ll`
$ echo $l 
total 1408 -rwxrwxr-x. 1 xiaohan xiaohan 229 Oct 7 22:50 run.sh -rwxrwxr-x. 1 xiaohan xiaohan 229 Oct 7 22:56 test.sh -rwxrwxr-x. 1 xiaohan xiaohan 1326459 Oct 2 17:29 TMalign -rw-r--r--. 1 xiaohan xiaohan 104175 Oct 2 17:29 TMalign.f
```

As you can see from the above example, the output becomes one line.

What is happening here? How to recover the output to the originally multiline format?

Comment: Did you try `echo "$l"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you wrap a variable in double quotes, its expansion undergoes word splitting, which causes all sequences of whitespace to be collapsed into a single word break. So write:

```
echo "$l"
```

You should generally quote your variables unless you know you're in a context where you want word splitting and wildcard expansion to occur on it.